# Trying to add sections with headers to UITableViewController (iOS)

Tags: ios, uitableview, sections

I'm still very new to objective-c, and I've looked all for an answer. I haven't been able to successfully implement anything I've found yet. I'm using an open source sliding menu that I found, and I haven't found anything that fits within the code it uses. (I'd post a link to it, but I can't remember where I found it.)

EDIT: I've got the sections added. Now, I just need to make it so the first cell in the second section only shows up in the first section. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ59S.png

I've updated the code below. Here's a reference of what I'm trying to do. Right now, cell 1 shows up in both section 1 and section 2.

SECTION 1: (no header)
- cell 1: "Search Nouns"

SECTION 2: "Noun Conjugation"
- cell 2: "Regular Nouns"
- cell 3: "Irregular Nouns"
- cell 4: "Uncountable Nouns"

```
#import "BaseTableViewController.h"
#import "KYSlideMenuViewController.h"

@interface BaseTableViewController () {
    int   _currentCtrNum;
}

@end

@implementation BaseTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // 最初に表示するビューを設定する
    _currentCtrNum = -1;
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
}

#pragma mark -

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2 ;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 4;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(section==0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 25;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 0)
        return @"";

    else
        return @"reference";

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"名詞検索";
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Side B";
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Side C";
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Side D";
        default:
            break;
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] ; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
        if (i == indexPath.row) {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        } else {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }

    // 現在のビューコントローラなら表示するだけ
    if (_currentCtrNum == indexPath.row) {
        [(KYSlideMenuViewController *)self.parentViewController slideChildTo:KYS_CLOSE];
        return;
    }
    _currentCtrNum = (int)indexPath.row;

    // 新しいビューコントローラを生成してコンテナのビューコントローラを入れ替え
    UIViewController *toCtr;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0: // noun search
            toCtr = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"itemTableView"];
            break;
        case 1: // navigationあり
            toCtr = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainView"];
            break;
        case 2: // navigationなし
            toCtr = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"subView"];
            break;
        case 3: // navigationあり
            toCtr = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"srdView"];
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    [(KYSlideMenuViewController *)self.parentViewController changeTo:toCtr];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

There also supposed to be a delegate for `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` where you would return 2;

Comment: The method is `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. Now, I just need to figure out how to not display that first cell in the second section. http://i.imgur.com/gSIRNJ3.png

Comment: You'll need logic based on the value of `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`